# Java - Read data from DB and make label + button according to the info

Tags: java, database, loops

I'm going to ask a huge favor here.

I have a view that when it opens, it should show every beverage from the database, and show that on the screen.

It also has to add a `+` button, an amount label next to it, and a `-` button. This should be done for every item.

The tables I'm getting the items from is called `dhh_item` by the way.

Now, I've got this:

```
public ArrayList<Item> getBeverages(Item item) {
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

    if (item != null) {
        // First open a database connnection
        DatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection(); 
        if (connection.openConnection()) {
            // If a connection was successfully setup, execute the SELECT statement.
            ResultSet resultset = connection.executeSQLSelectStatement(
                    "SELECT * FROM dhh_item ");

            if (resultset != null) {
                try {
                    while (resultset.next()) {
                        String itemName = resultset.getString("itemName");
                        String status = resultset.getString("status");
                        String description = resultset.getString("description");
                        int price = resultset.getInt("price");

                        Item newItem = new Item(itemName, status, description, price);

                        items.add(newItem);
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                    items.clear();
                }
            }
            // else an error occurred leave array list empty.

            // We had a database connection opened. Since we're finished,
            // we need to close it.
            connection.closeConnection();
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

Is this correct in any way. Would I retrieve any data at all? (The `.getString()`'s are correct.)

Now, this method is inside of another Class (ItemDAO).

Can I call this from my view? How would I get it to make a new label + button for each?

Thanks a lot for those who could help me out on this one!

At the end, it should be looking like this:

[image]

for each beverage in the table.

Comment: You are using Swing ??

Answer (score 0):

Sounds rather straigh forward

```
Collection<Item> items=dao.getBeverages(someItem) // get all items
    for(Item item:items){
        label=new JLabel(item.getYourItemNameOrLabelOrhatever) // this will be the "coca-cola"
        incButton=new JButton(incrementButtonAction); // craete/get some action 
        decButton=new JButton(decrementButtonAction); // same here
        counter=new JLabel("0");
        yourContainer.add(label);
        yourContainer.add(incButton);
        yourContainer.add(label);
        yourContainer.add(decButton);
        yourContainer.revalidate();
}
```